# Evaluate $\int_C\overline{z}dz$ using parametrization: $z=\sqrt{4-y^2}+iy \; (-2\le y\le 2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

**Background:** This is Brown, Churchill, Complex Variables ch 4,sec42, prob 9

**My attempt:** $$\int_{-2}^{2}(\sqrt{4-y^2}-iy)\overset{\frac{dz}{dy}}{\overbrace{\left (\frac{-y}{\sqrt{4-y^2}}+i\right )}}dy$$
$$\int_{-2}^{2}i\left (\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{4-y^2}}+\sqrt{4-y^2} \right ) dy
$$
$$\int_{-2}^{2}i\left (\frac{4}{\sqrt{4-y^2}}\right )dy\tag{1}$$
$$\int_{-2}^{2}\left (\frac{-4}{\sqrt{y^2-4}}\right )dy$$
$$-4\cosh^{-1}(y/2)|_{-2}^2$$
Now aside from arccos having a branch cut along the real axis $(-\infty,1)$ making it undefined, what did I do wrong if anything. (Noting at line 1 integrating as $\left[ 4i\sin^{-1}(y/2)\right ]_{-2}^{2}$ gives $4\pi i$. I've tried using the [definition](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/arc_10.pdf) to see if the answers are interchangeable along [some branch cut](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%204i%20arcsin%20and%20-4%20arccosh).
$$-\cosh^{-1}(z)=-\ln(z+(z^2-1)^{1/2})$$ $$=-\ln(z+|z^2-1|^{1/2}e^{i/2\arg(z^2-1)})=-\ln(z+|z^2-1|^{1/2}e^{i/2[\arg(1-z^2)+\pi]})$$ $$=-\ln(z+i|1-z^2|^{1/2}e^{i/2\arg(1-z^2)})=-\ln(z+i(1-z^2)^{1/2})$$

Which is starting to look like $\sin^{-1}(z)=-i\ln[iz+(1-z^2)^{1/2}]$
I may be one reciprocal and power of i away if someone can help me.

On a related note, how could I convert an answer when integrating $$\frac{d}{dz}\cos^{-1}(z)=\frac{-1}{(1-z^2)^{1/2}}$$
$$\frac{d}{dz}\sin^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{(1-z^2)^{1/2}}$$

What shows $-1\cdot\cos^{-1}(z)=i\ln[z+i(1-z^2)^{1/2}]=\sin^{-1}=-i\ln[iz+(1-z^2)^{1/2}]$? I'm interested in a link or calculation.

Comment: Notice that $\int_{-2} ^2 \Bbb i \frac 4 {\sqrt {4-y^2}} \ \Bbb dy$ can be computed directly as $4 \Bbb i \arcsin \frac y 2 \Big| _{-2} ^2 = 4 \pi \Bbb i$, without the need to play with $\Bbb i$ and hyperbolic functions.

Comment: So, C is the circle with centre O and radius 2 ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: No, just the right half-circle.

Comment: yes, evaluating at (1) with arcsin is much easier, but I was wondering why the way I tried may not work or be right, so that I don't guess when solving. There's a reason for everything.

Comment: and the question specifically states you can't use $2e^{i\theta}$ to travel the circle around the right half (see wording).

Comment: A simple reason for this pitfall is that change of variable $y \rightarrow iy$ is not allowed in (Riemann) integrals.

Comment: @JeanMarie: There is no such change of variable there, take a look again.

Comment: Passing from $\int_{-2}^{2}i\left (\frac{4}{\sqrt{4-y^2}}\right )dy\tag{1}$ to the next line is equivalent to the unallowed change of variable $y \rightarrow iy$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: No, passing from one line to the other is just taking a $-1$ out of the square root in the denominator. The change of variable that you speak about would have transformed that denominator into $\sqrt {4 + y^2}$ (notice the "plus" sign).

Comment: Indeed ! You are completely right, I did a mistake. But now I see another reason. In the integral $\int_{-2}^{2}\left (\frac{-4}{\sqrt{y^2-4}}\right )dy$, the function which is under the integral sign (the "integrand") is not defined between the bounds [-2,2], thus the following line cannot be written...

Comment: I think in complex analysis that's allowed, otherwise i wouldn't be allowed when integrating along the y-axis either.

Comment: @user135711: You suspect correctly that it's a matter of branch cuts. The usual choice is along $(-\infty,1]$, which makes $\cosh ^{-1} (-1)$ problematic. You can find all the needed information on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function#Principal_value_of_the_inverse_hyperbolic_cosine), on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicCosine.html) and on [the NIST site](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.37).